# Can't mass-assign attributes in nested form despite specifying in attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

So I have a couple models user and memoir.

User.rb

```
  has_many :memoirs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memoirs

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :memoir_attributes
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

and Memoir.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :content, :birth, :death, :name, :subdomain

  validates_uniqueness_of :subdomain
```

However when I save (the memoir is nested inside the user form) I get this message and the memoir doesn't save: "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: memoir"

Confused

Comment: Shoot figured it out in my fields_for in the view I had put :memoir instead of :memoirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
has_many :memoirs
```

and

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :memoirs
```

So surely

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :memoir_attributes
```

Should be

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :memoirs_attributes
```

?

If I have that wrong then check your log file. That should tell you what the issue is